# How to communicate between Firefox addon and android process?

Tags: android, firefox-addon

I want to write an Firefox mobile addon, which needs to communicate or invoke some android program with some data. I want to know what is the best way to communicate between an Firefox addon and android process. One way I can think of is to write data on Clipboard from addon, and continuously poll for clipboard from the android process, but that is not the efficient way. So any other ideas, please.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there isn't a public way to communicate between Firefox and Android. We have been discussing how to expose such a mechanism.

In the meantime, I have been able to communicate with other applications using sockets. For example, the Android Scripting Layer (http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) can act as a RPC server. I have been able to open a socket to the server and communicate that way.

Comment: Is intents the way to go now? https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-for-android-addons/blob/355f9a01464a0794c1084e8fdbab92c58503f49a/snippets/jni.js#L23-L44

Answer (score 1):

The [FoxToPhone](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtophone-aka-sendtophone/) allows to send data from the browser to android device. Could be a good example to follow.

In the meantime, the [cloud to device](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/android/c2dm/index.html) allows to send data from the cloud to a phone.

Maybe a combination of both services could do the trick?

Comment: unnecessary internet dependency?

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSockets in your FF extension and Sockets in your android app.

Or another solution is to include a servlet (appengine) between the extension and the app.